# Pull name and ID strings from facebook login?

Tags: php, android, mysql, facebook

I have a basic app that logs in on Facebook, and `onSuccess` the user is shown a map with users GPS location.

I need to upload the users name and ID to a database, preferably mysql and php.

I have no idea how to go about this with the Facebook API, I don't know how to do it. I have my `mainActivity` as this;

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.LoginManager;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    private TextView info;
    private LoginButton loginButton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
        loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

        loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapActivity.class));

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {
                info.setText("Login attempt cancelled.");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
            }

        });
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
// Hide the status bar.
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
// Remember that you should never show the action bar if the
// status bar is hidden, so hide that too if necessary.
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

The MySQL part is easy enough, and the PHP I think I can manage, but how do I getName strings and so on from Facebook and parse it to PHP?

Answer (score 2):

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(), (json, response) -> {
                        if (response.getError() == null) {
                            //get the info here.
                            String name = json.getString("name");
                            String id = json.getString("id");
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Awesome! Can I just throw that in the OnSuccess method ?

Answer (score 2):

For FB SDK 4.0 you can get those params as follows:

```
Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
Log.d("facebook id",profile.getId());
Log.d("facebook name",profile.getFirstName());
```

Comment: Cool :) How do I got about implementing it into the code? In the onSuccess method? I'm very new at android

Comment: yes, you will have to write above lines in onSuccess method